# mysql / sql fixing rows in many to many database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a many to many table that has multiple rows that are duplicates due to an error in import.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `actor` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` text NOT NULL,
 `pic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `dob` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `pic_id` (`pic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3195 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `video_actor` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `actor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),
 KEY `actor_id` (`actor_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `video_actor_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`) REFERENCES `actor` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23757 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/utMWuGDbpgirV2jTxjHraR/3)

Specifically I have an actor table with

```
table actor
actor.id (pk)
actor.name
```

and I have duplicate actor names

they are linked through the table video_actor to video as so:

```
table video_actor
id (pk)
actor_id (fk)
video_id (fk)

table video
id (pk)
...etc
```

I tried for a few hours to make a SQL query to update the linking table (video_actor) with the correct id but I failed. The closest I feel I got is:

```
UPDATE video_actor as x
join 
(
   SELECT min_id,max_id
      FROM (
   SELECT name, MIN(id) as min_id,MAX(id) as max_id
      FROM actor
   GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
   ) AS y
) as q on x.video_id = q.min_id
SET x.actor_id = q.min_id
WHERE x.actor_id = q.max_id;
```

the above query does nothing so I wrote some php to do what I couldn't do in pure sql:

```
public function remove_dup_actors() {
    $sql="
        SELECT name,min_id,max_id
        FROM (
            SELECT name, MIN(id) as min_id,MAX(id) as max_id
            FROM actor
            GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
        ) as dups;
    ";
    $actor_dups=self::$dB->get_rows($sql);
    foreach($actor_dups as $actor) {
        $sql="UPDATE video_actor SET actor_id=${actor['min_id']} WHERE actor_id=${actor['max_id']}";
        self::$dB->update_row($sql);
        echo "Updated ${actor['name']}\n";
        $sql="DELETE FROM actor WHERE id=${actor['max_id']}";
        self::$dB->update_row($sql);
    }
}
```

this works.

Please experts, can someone tell me what is wrong with my pure sql (failed) solution?

UPDATE:
Tried:

```
UPDATE video_actor as x
join 
(
   SELECT id,min_id,max_id
      FROM (
         SELECT id, name, MIN(id) as min_id,MAX(id) as max_id
         FROM actor
         GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
      ) AS y
   ) as q on x.video_id = y.id
SET x.actor_id = q.min_id
WHERE x.actor_id = q.max_id;
```

and get unknown column y.id on ON clause

Comment: You say `this works`, so what is the issue? Should make `actor.name` unique, but I think you'd run into issues with that approach as well. Names aren't that unique of a string.

Comment: @user3783243 it works as separate queries called from PHP but doesn't as a single SQL query

Comment: The `remove_dup_actors` though would `update` and `delete` all duplicate records though so this issue shouldn't be present after.

Comment: The php solves the issue, but I wanted to solve it with an sql query, I thought I could but couldn't the sql returns 0 rows affected with duplicates in the name column. I wanted to know what was wrong with my attempt to solve it in pure sql.

Comment: Looks like you have wrong condition in your join: `on x.video_id = q.min_id`. If I get it right that the `min_id` corresponds to `actor_id`.

Comment: @Jared tried to add the index but still can work it out

Comment: This question would be a lot more clear if you would simply provide table schema, and some sample data.  Consider creating a https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @Eaten by a Grue ok, done

Comment: Much better - see my answer below. Also, *please do not post images of your schema*. In general, do not post any images of code here at all. The only time you should be posting images is if your question is directly related to an image. To post schema, post the same CREATE TABLE statements you used in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from your question what the "*correct id*" is, but I'm assuming you want the lowest id of all rows with the same `actor.name`. This should do it:

```sql
UPDATE actor a
    JOIN video_actor v ON v.actor_id = a.id
    JOIN (
      SELECT MIN(id) as min_id, a2.name
      FROM actor a2
      GROUP BY a2.name
    ) a2 ON a2.name = a.name
SET v.actor_id = a2.min_id;
```

First we join the two tables on `id/actor_id` then we can update `video_actor` based on the first id belonging to a given `name`.

You'll need to deal with eliminating dupes with some separate queries. Here is an example of how to do it on the `actor` table by joining rows to the same subquery we used in above on `name` but which do not match `min_id`:

```sql
DELETE a
FROM actor a
    JOIN (
      SELECT MIN(id) as min_id, a2.name
      FROM actor a2
      GROUP BY a2.name
    ) a2 ON a2.name = a.name AND a.id != a2.min_id;
```

Also, I think you should probably be using `VARCHAR` for datatype of `actor.name` with an index - that will make this much faster.

Comment: Thanks! It seems so simple when you see the answer :)
and yes the lowest id is correct

Comment: @T'rip - if it seems simple that's a good sign. Another tip - you can build `SELECT` statements of the datasets you want to manipulate and then transform them into `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.  If you replace `UPDATE` in my first query with `SELECT * FROM` you can easily see how the data is assembled. Then you can play with it until you're satisfied with the results and `UPDATE` away.